# Installing Windows 8 after Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, windows, windows-8

I was using windows 8.1 and I was get bored of it and than i installed ubuntu on it. The mistake i done was that i erased windows 8 and then installed ubuntu and now I want to use multi-boot. I want to install both OS. When the windows setup runs it says " We couldn't find any drives..." . Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: the thing is that i have unallocated space in drive to install windows but it's still saying " we couldn't find any drives..." !

Comment: "When the windows setup runs it says " We couldn't find any drives..."" is a windows problem; not Ubuntu.

Comment: but it came after installing ubuntu.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and the people here are very good at dual-booting and removing Windows, **but not very good at getting it back once it was removed...**  However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at deleting Ubuntu and installing Windows, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Gparted and create a NTFS partition to install Windows on. But I once tried to do that and came across this error :

> windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style.

Since you installed Ubuntu first the whole disk is probably in GPT partition style. The solution I found was to backup data and create a live Gparted USB. Use that to create MBR partition table and then install Windows and later Ubuntu.

Hope this helps. :)